# WinForms ContextMenuStrip item shortcuts conflict with IME (Chinese/Japanese)

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, contextmenu, ime

Our Windows Forms application has a custom ContextMenuStrip for a textbox.
The ContextMenuStrip items have the ampersand shortcut keys (e.g. `Select &All`) such that if the user performs <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>, it will call the "Select All" click handler.

This works fine in English IME.
However, if I switch to Chinese or Japanese IME, after <kbd>Right-Click</kbd>, if I press another letter in the keyboard, instead of calling the context menu shortcut, it will bringout the IME options in the textbox. This renders the shortcuts useless.

This behaviour does not occur in standard Windows Textboxes.
Any idea how to fix this? I have dabbled with Focus() and ImeMode to no avail.

By the way, the textbox is not restricted to any particular IME (should support all languages).

And just to clarify, I have also enabled keyboard Shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> on the ContextMenu/Textbox, but that is a different thing. My question is for the <kbd>right-click</kbd> + <kbd>letter</kbd> shortcut.

Thanks in advance.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the issue because my environment only has English. However, one idea is after right click on the textbox, use `Win32 pinvoke` methods to find the textbox context menu, and try setting the focus on it. It is strange the TextBox still has the input focus after the context menu pops up.